# How do I save a variable in a class without the variable being lost through class inheritance

Tags: python, class, oop

I want it so that when the `active()` function Is called in the `StopSign` class, it calls the `stop()` function in the `Car` class. However, in my actual code(code is kinda long and distractingly sloppy so I used this one so you can get the idea) when I call upon the `active` function `StopSign object has no attribute 'movement_code'`. How can I get around this?

```
class Car:
    def __init__(self):
        self.color = blue
        more code
    def go(self):
        self.movement_code = movement_function
    def stop:
        self.movement_code.kill()
class StopSign(car):
    def __init__(self):
        some code
    def active(self):
        self.stop()
```

Comment: There are some syntactic problems here, but also a class design problem. A StopSign is not a Car, so it shouldn’t inherit from it.

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy so how would I access the ```stop``` function without having to initialize the car class again?

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're having is that `StopSign` wasn't initializing its parent class and so didn't inherit the `stop` method. Besides that though I agree with Arya. It doesn't make sense to have the `StopSign` class inherit from the `Car` class.

```
class Car:
    def __init__(self):
        self.color = 'blue'
        # more code

    def go(self):
        pass
        # self.movement_code = movement_function

    def stop(self):
        pass
        # self.movement_code.kill()


class StopSign(Car):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        pass
        # some code

    def active(self):
        self.stop()


sign = StopSign()
sign.active()
```

Here is a simple example of how you could avoid to have `StopSign` subclass `Car`:

```
class Car:
    def __init__(self):
        self.color = 'blue'

    def go(self):
        pass

    def stop(self):
        pass


class StopSign:
    def __init__(self):
        self.cars_in_vicinity = []

    def active(self):
        for car in self.cars_in_vicinity:
            car.stop()


car = Car()
sign = StopSign()
sign.cars_in_vicinity.append(car)
sign.active()
```

There are many other ways to approach this though.